# Precompile a TypeScript object into variable

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

## Question (TLDR)

Is there any way I can precompile a TypeScript object and inject it to my application?

## What I'm trying to achieve

1. Run a TypeScript function (with own dependencies) to parse a `yaml` file during compilation time.
2. Inject the resulting object into the application that'll render it in a web application.

## Background

I have a [Vue application](https://github.com/undergroundwires/privacy.sexy) that parses [a big `yaml` file](https://github.com/undergroundwires/privacy.sexy/blob/master/src/application/application.yaml), and builds an [`Application.ts`](https://github.com/undergroundwires/privacy.sexy/blob/master/src/domain/Application.ts) object that's used throughout the project. The parsing happens when the application is initialized on users browser.

The parser [`ApplicationParser.ts`](https://github.com/undergroundwires/privacy.sexy/blob/master/src/application/Parser/ApplicationParser.ts) is written in TypeScript and I'd like to keep it that way.

Unfortunately construction of the object is a bit heavy process and I'd like to do the parsing and building of object during compilation instead of doing it on each user browser session.

## Solutions considered

1. Use `vue.config.js` to inject stuff at compile time.

   - **Challenge**: it's JavaScript only and there are [no updates](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2138#issuecomment-677635585) regarding a potential `vue.config.ts`.
2. Write a custom webpack loader using TypeScript that will load a yaml file and call [`ApplicationParser.ts`](https://github.com/undergroundwires/privacy.sexy/blob/master/src/application/Parser/ApplicationParser.ts) and inject returned [`Application.ts`](https://github.com/undergroundwires/privacy.sexy/blob/master/src/domain/Application.ts) to the application.

   - **Challenge** the [the official example](https://webpack.js.org/contribute/writing-a-loader/#simple) for a custom webpack loader is written in JavaScript and I've never seen any example of a loader written in Typescript.

Comment: You can write your config in ts and run `tsc -m commonjs --esModuleInterop vue.config.ts` in console to compile it into `vue.config.js`. Then you gitignore whichever makes more sense for your deployment process. Example here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/2138#issuecomment-677635585

Comment: Hi @tao, thanks for quick reply. I tried that, however it does not compile the TypeScript file and it does not include its dependencies. It just converts `import` of the TypeScript parser into a `require` in `vue.config.js` which does not work as that TypeScript class also `import`s other `.ts` classes.